# Oozie launcher job does not end

Tags: hadoop, oozie

> I have an oozie workflow that performs a hive action (eg insert overwrite table ...). The result of the hive statement is already there, but the oozie launcher job has been running. It is not over. Is there a comrade who has encountered this problem?The log of nodes executing the launcher job is as follows It keeps printing the memory information and does not end.

```
>nodemanager log:


2018-06-26 16:15:33,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:36,787 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:39,807 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:42,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:45,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:48,849 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:51,868 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:54,882 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:15:57,896 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:16:00,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:16:03,929 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:16:06,944 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:16:09,958 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
2018-06-26 16:16:12,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 121958 for container-id container_1529902421597_0201_01_000001: 777.4 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used
...
```

Comment: Please consider pasting a log (such as the nodemanager log) as text in your question, rather than providing an image with it. Please then also format the log as code (with four spaces before each line).

Comment: What are the steps/research you have tried to kill the job or to find the root cause?

Comment: Launcher job does not end the task resources can not be released, has found the reason, thank you very much